# notice on non-object and undefined variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve wrong answers for each question by constructing the list of wrong answers in PHP. For example bycontaining a single row from the original query, to compute the wrong answers like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, an.Answer, an.AnswerId 
   FROM Session s  
   INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId 
   JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId 
   WHERE s.SessionName = ? 
   ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer 
   "; 
       
   // prepare query 
   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query); 
   // You only need to call bind_param once 
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment); 
   // execute query 
   $stmt->execute();  
   
   $specialOptionTypes = array( 
    'Yes or No' => array( 'Y', 'N' ), 
    'True or False' => array( 'T', 'F' ), 
); 

// Do this for each row: 
if ( array_key_exists( $row->OptionType, $specialOptionTypes ) ) { 
    $options = $specialOptionTypes[ $row->OptionType ]; 
} else if ( preg_match( '/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $row->OptionType, $match ) ) { 
    $options = range( $match[1], $match[2] ); 
} else { 
    // issue warning about unrecognized option type 
    $options = array(); 
} 
$right = str_split( $row->Answer );  // or explode() on a delimiter, if any 
$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right ); 



    // Fetch the results into an array 

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db) 
   $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionNo, $dbAnswer, $dbAnswerId); 
      while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
         
      $incorrect_ans[] = $wrong; 

      }     
       
       
      .... 
       
      //table row 
       
      <td class="answertd" name="incorrectanswers[]"><?php
echo $incorrect_ans[$key];
?></td>
```

The problem I am having though is that I am not getting the wrong answers but instead I am receiving a couple of errors:

First error is for any `$row` variable which is shown in code above where it states:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in ... on line ...
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ... on line ...

Second issue is in the table row above instead of displaying the incorrect answer, it displays `Array`.

My question is how can notices and array be fixed to at least have an error free application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't initialize `$row` to something outside that if statement, then it's undefined.

This means `$row` is not an object, probably it's NULL or false in some cases (nothing found) due to it's not accessible. Out of scope

Comment: Ah ok, will something mysqli-fetch_object be able to sort this one out? I am trying to achieve to match this link: http://ideone.com/fqKZMd but not sure what changes I need to do in order to be able to retrieve incorrect answers. Do you have an idea on this?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you are asking

Comment: Its ok, I will ask it as a separate question. I need to explain it a bit better. Thanks for your help.